# DecimalFormat parse returns 0.0

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting, decimalformat

OK So...

Simply put, my DecimalFormat seems to not be working. I'm an absolute java scrub and don't really know what I'm doing here, but I feel like I should ask the question anyways. So here goes.

When I attempt to parse the value from the two JTextFields accountBalanceField and interestRateField, it doesn't fail but rather simply returns 0. The catch statement should be printing the error stack if it encounters an error, but it simply doesn't encounter an error and returns 0.

Any ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

In the import statement it says that even though I am clearly declaring two new DecimalFormat type variables, the import is still "unused".

```
DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###.##%");

    try {
        Number balanceDouble = df1.parse(accountBalanceField.getText());
        mAccountBalance = balanceDouble.doubleValue();
        System.out.println(mAccountBalance);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Number interestDouble = df2.parse(interestRateField.getText());
        mInterestRate = interestDouble.doubleValue() / 100.0;
        mAccountBalance += mAccountBalance * mInterestRate;
        accountBalanceField.setText("$" + String.valueOf(mAccountBalance));
        System.out.println(mInterestRate);
        System.out.println(mAccountBalance);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the text you parse is a valid number, for example by printing it?

Comment: Can you provide the input values that you are having a problem with?